# Streams and TCP protocol

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I have this small piece of code. I run it, and then connect with a Telnet client.

```
var net = require('net');


//create server
var server = net.createServer(function (conn) {
    console.log('New connection!')

    //Message to the one who connects.
    conn.write (
        '\n > Welcome to NODE-CHAT!'
        + '\n > ' + count + ' other people are connected at this time.'
        + '\n > Please write your name and press Enter: '
    );

    //When a connected user writes...
    conn.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    conn.setEncoding('utf8');
});


//Listen
server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on *:3000');
})
```

When connected i get the Welcome messages as expected... Then if i write something in the telnet client, it will immediately trigger the conn.on listener... Lets say i write "hi you" the output in the console will be:

h

i

y

o

u

I would like this messages to sent when it is "finished" instead whenever i type  character. I guess i could store the data from the conn.on trigger in a string, and output this string when the '\n' character is typed.

*But I'm wondering if this is the right way to do it. Is there a way to change what trigger the conn.on? Maybe so it will only trigger (that is output in this case... ) on certain characters?... namely the \n char.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a stream of data so you should not make any assumptions about how much data you will receive by calling `.read()` or when listening for `data` events.

If your input is newline delimited, then you will have to buffer until you see a newline. There could also be multiple newlines in one chunk passed to your `data` event handlers too.

Comment: Ok, so how do I change my code above to take the text written in the telnet client, and output this in the console when "enter" is pressed in the telnet client??... preferably on the same row aswell =)

Comment: You just do as you suggested earlier, write the data to a string variable. Then loop through your string variable looking for any newlines and at the end only keep data after the last newline in your string variable.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how the data-chunk could contain several (newline or whatever) characters... as it seems to trigger instantly every time I press a keyboard key in the telnet client

Comment: It may or may not be just one character per data chunk. You should not make any assumptions, telnet or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems in your code. The behavior you describe is related to the Telnet client that sends every keystroke, it does not wait for you to hit enter. If you are on Linux try sending data with wget o open a browser and type

```
http://localhost:3000/hiyou
```

and see if you get a complete string instead of one character.